# Using version 1.3 of glDatePicker. Need to set the default startdate to 01/01/1994

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Using version 1.3 of glDatePicker with jquery. Need to set the default startdate to 01/01/1994.

My HTML Code:

```
<span class='input'>
    <span class='icon-calendar'></span>
    <input type='text' class='player-birthdate input-unstyled datepicker' id='roster-player-birthdate-$playerseq' value='$startdate'>
</span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('.datepicker').glDatePicker({ 
        zIndex: 100 
     });
}
```

I want to set the Start date to '01/01/1994' but don't know how to do this. I'm not really familiar with jQuery yet so this may be simple.

Samples in version 2 show that I could do the following but this does not work:

```
$('.datepicker').glDatePicker({ 
    setStartDate: date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1994)) 
});
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. Anyone have any suggestions?

1.3 glDatePicker.js file defines the methods:

```
(function($)
var defaults =
{
    callId: 0,
    cssName: 'default',
    startDate: -1,
    ...
};
var methods = 
{
    init:...
    show:...
    hide:..
    setStartDate: function(e) { $(this).data("settings").startDate = e; },
    setEndDate: ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine this way:

`$('.datepicker').glDatePicker({
    startDate: new Date("January 1, 1994")
});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,It Works for me.:

```
$('#dob').glDatePicker({
  selectableDateRange: [
   { from: new Date(1900, 1, 1),
    to: new Date() },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
 $('.datepicker').glDatePicker({
    selectedDate: new Date(1994, 1, 1)
 });
```

Comment: I would expect this to automatically set the date to 1/1/1994 but it doesn't. I think I'm going to have to upgrade to 2.0 glDatePicker to get this to work.